# How do I create an environment variable "openssl"

Tags: ubuntu, bash, environment-variables, openssl

I know my question may sound stupid but there's some problem I've been fighting with for the last 2 days.

I have a few versions of OpenSSL installed on Ubuntu server.

The one which is desired is located at `/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64/openssl`

What I want to do is when I type `openssl` in virtually any directory it would go to the latest version and execute openssl commands respectively.

How do I do that? I've tried to just set an environment variable called `openssl` but with no luck.

```
export OPENSSL=/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64/openssl
```

Output of `echo $OPENSSL`

```
/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64/openssl
```

With no luck means whenever I type `openssl`

I get

```
The program 'openssl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install openssl
```

I know that it has something to do with usr/openssl configs. But I don't remember how I did it last time :(

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure that the folder containing the openssl bin you want is first in your $PATH... OR you could create an alias. Doing either of these might mess up anything that's dependent on a different version of openssl though. To put in your PATH, open your `~/.bashrc` or one of your shells rc files and look to see if there's a `export $PATH:...` anywhere. What you'd do is `export $PATH=/path/to/openssl/folder:$PATH` (note the colon). Then you can logout/in or resource the file `source ~/.bashrc` and try. Might help ya. OH! I see this was asked years ago. lol. I'll leave this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how environment variables work. When you run `somecommand`, the shell *does not care* about variables like $somecommand or $SOMECOMMAND. It would use the environment variable only if you actually typed `$OPENSSL` instead of `openssl`. For example:

```
# ASDF=/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64/openssl

# $ASDF version
OpenSSL 1.1.0
```

(Some programs do care – for example, Makefiles and "./configure" scripts are frequently written to look for variables like $PYTHON – but that's not the general case.)

The one environment variable that *could* help in your case is **$PATH**, which contains a list of directories to search for commands. If you put the directory containing 'openssl' in front of the current $PATH value, then running `openssl` will always look in that directory first:

```
PATH="/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64:$PATH"
```

For example:

```
# which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

# export PATH="/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64:$PATH"

# which openssl
/opt/cprocsp/cp-openssl-1.1.0/bin/amd64/openssl
```